# How can I click <a> wiyh scapy-splash

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrapy, scrapy-splash

url:http(s)://bbs.ngacn.cc/nuke.php?__lib=login&__act=login_ui

```
<a id="showcaptchad" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="showCaptchad(this)">xxxxxxxx</a> 


script = ''' 
 function main(splash)
 splash.images_enabled = false
 splash.resource_timeout = 100.0
 splash:autoload('http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js')
 assert(splash:go(splash.args.url))
 splash:wait(1)
 splash:runjs("$('#showcaptchad').click()")
 splash:wait(0.5)
 return splash:html()
end
'''
```

it never works.
but

```
document.getElementById("showcaptchad").click()
```

worked well

question:

1.Whether jQuery does not support  click() .

2.how can I click the link like

```
<a tabindex="-1" href="#J_Reviews" rel="nofollow" hidefocus="true" data-index="1">xxxxxxx<em class="J_ReviewsCount" style="display: inline;">62791</em></a>
```

or

```
<a href="?spm=a220o.1000855.0.0.JZj6pP&amp;page=2" data-spm-anchor-id="a220o.1000855.0.0">2</a>
```

they don't contain id='xxx' or name='xxx' .

I can't use 'getElementById()' or 'getElementsByName()'.

what should I do?

I just want to click once

why so hard (╯°口°)╯(┴—┴

## ===============================================

After 100000000 times

```
splash:runjs('document.querySelector("#showcaptchad").click()')
```

this worked

it looks like not jQuery method

===============================================
I was shown how to do this just now

To use getElementById, getElementByName, getElementsByTagName() and some simple

function can almost do everything

jQuery looks like not necessary

Comment: If the element you are trying to select doesn't have an id or name then how would you identify it? You would need to have some means of identifying it, whether that be a class and/or `data-` or other attribute, in which case you can use `querySelector()`. The jQuery `.click()` method triggers the associated event handler but not the default anchor click behaviour, but `$('#showcaptchad')[0].click()` will have the same effect as `document.getElementById("showcaptchad").click()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [Javascript onclick handler](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) or you can select the element with the [jquery atribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```js
$('a[href=#J_Reviews]').click(function(){
  alert('jQuery way')
})

function myFunction(){
  alert('Javascriptway');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a tabindex="-1" href="#J_Reviews" rel="nofollow" hidefocus="true" data-index="1">xxxxxxx<em class="J_ReviewsCount" style="display: inline;" >62791</em></a>
or

<a href="?spm=a220o.1000855.0.0.JZj6pP&amp;page=2" data-spm-anchor-id="a220o.1000855.0.0" onclick="myFunction()">2</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use this to listen click event

```
$('a[href=#J_Reviews]').on('click',function(){
  alert("jQuery way too");
});
```